# Assigning object reference to a Variant/Long

Tags: vba, ms-access, object, adodb

I have sometime some error like this: "Required object" (translate from my french error.)

But I can't understand what is exactly an object in VBA (with Access, if it's change something).

For example, I have do an SQL SELECT with ADODB.recordset and I see in the spy of the Access IDE for VBA, the value is an "Variant/Long". Okay, I create an Long variable and I set the value of query in the long variable.
`Set userId = RS.Fields(0).value`
But it's doesn't work...

At the start, I have think: the object is like an array. But the array already exist in VBA.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyd4tfw8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) set of articles will help you get a clear understanding of using objects in VBA.

Comment: @Jens: the link you gave is for VB.NET, which is not the same as VBA, though there is some degree of overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Long` data type can hold a 32-bit integer. It isn't an object reference, so don't use `Set`.

```
Dim userId As Long
userId = RS.Fields(0).value
```

For more on what is and isn't an object, see [Data Type Summary for VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).